# Can't remove selected="selected" from select option

Tags: jquery

I i trie to remove the part selected="selected" from a select box.

This is the select box

```
<select id="editsite_TREE_PARENT_ID" name="newsite_TREE_PARENT_ID" class="form-control input-medium">
          <option value="ROOT">root</option>
          <option value="1" selected="selected">index</option>
          <option value="2">impressum</option>                                                          
</select>
```

Ans this is like i try to do it, but it wont work - nothing happens and i dont know why?`

```
$("#editsite_TREE_PARENT_ID").find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");'
```

Changing to

```
$("#editsite_TREE_PARENT_ID").find("option[selected]").removeAttr("selected");
```

solve the problem, but now i have a new problem.

After i remove the selection and set a new selection for a option the current option will not display as selected in the drop down box (in sourcode but not display). I mean the option is not pre-selected. What can be the reason for it?

Comment: It seems to work here: https://jsfiddle.net/ha630r09/4/. Click the button and you'll notice the `selected` option change. I might be missing a part of your question though.

Comment: It is working fine

Comment: yes i see, in my code nothing happens, and i dont know why...

Comment: You might be not using jquery library. check snipppet below

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not doing anything because the selected attribute is based on the active/current selection in the dropdown, which isn't changing (behavior might be browser dependent). If you want to change it, try switching the selected index to whatever you want it to be instead. So something like this:

`$("#editsite_TREE_PARENT_ID").val(0)`

The jquery reference:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: if i try to switch the selected option before i remove the current one, i see two options wich are selected - did i missunderstoud something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That should work if the option with the selected attribute is currently selected, but if it isn't selected it wouldn't work.
The `:selected` selector looks for the currently selected option not the option with the selected attribute.

try

```
$("#editsite_TREE_PARENT_ID").find("option[selected]").removeAttr("selected");
```

Comment: Great, that works for me - but now i have the problem, that the selected=selected option is not shown on the seletbox as first element (selected element) !?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine.

```js
$("#target").click(function() {
  $("#editsite_TREE_PARENT_ID").find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="editsite_TREE_PARENT_ID" name="newsite_TREE_PARENT_ID" class="form-control input-medium">
          <option value="ROOT">root</option>
          <option value="1" selected="selected">index</option>
          <option value="2">impressum</option>                                    
</select>
<br><br>
<div id="target">click me</div>
```